# Update view and progress HUD whilest running method

Tags: xcode, view, hud

I have a method that converts an xml to JSON objects and loops trough them to possibly import data in my sqlite3 database.
Whilest running this method I would like to be able to let the user know how far (progress bar or circular) along the process the method is. But i can't seem to update the view until my methos is completely over.

Does anyone have an idea for this? I tried it almost all I guess.

[image: Xml import]
[image: setting progress percentage]
[image: only here Hud is shown]

Comment: Do your processing in the background so you can update the UI on the main thread.

Comment: Hi Maddy, have you got some kind of an example, because I tried this already with no success :(

Comment: thx, Maddy, restarted from scratch and now it works indead using background thread and all view updates in main thread

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved
Run method in **dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND**
And all progress and screen updates in **dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(**

[image]